# FIFO control signals and extraction of bits for routing logic

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am currently building a network-on-chip router in VHDL in order to implement a 64-core 2-D MESH network on an FPGA.Each core has its own router and each router has 5 ports (north , south , west , east ,local port for communication with the processing unit)
Each one of the ports have an input FIFO and an OUTPUT FIFO . So the input FIFO communicates with the outpuf fifo of the next destination router and the output fifo of this port with the input fifo of the source router.

My problem is that I am not using a Finite state machine to control the FIFOS write/read_eneable and FIFO_FULL FIFO_EMPTY signals and I do not know where these signals must be used in order to get the router working.

My FIFO is generated by xilinx CORE Generator and its a synchronous FIFO with the following signals : Input : Clock , Data in , read_enable , write_enable . Outputs : Data_out , fifo_full , fifo_empty , First 6 bits of the packet . This last output is used in order to get out of the fifo the first 6 bits of the packet in order to be used for routing decision by the XY routing block.

So my problem is that I cannot understand how to control the write/read_enable and fifo_full/empty of the FIFO and in addition how to extract the 6 bits in order to send them to the routing block.

Thank you in advance.

P.s. If anything is not clear please ask me to give further details.

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___*ANSWER REPLY* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____

Hello there simon!!I really appreciate the time spend to give your answer.

Basically I am going to have packets of 32bytes to process. So I must find a way to devide the packet into flits and then as the flits enter the FIFO the first 6 bits will be used for routing. This way I can simulate random traffic.

An example to give you to understand.
A 16-core mesh network has the following coordinates: 30 31 32 33
                                                      20 21 22 23
                                                      10 11 12 13
                                                      00 01 02 03

So imagine that each one of these 2bit number represent a router.
In this case we need 4 bits not 6.
So as the 4 bits enter the XY routing block. the first 2 bits are compared with the first bit of the coordinate and the second 2 bits are compared with the second bit of the coordinate.

So if we want to go from router 00 to router 22 the data coming into router 00 will have to be oriented to the correct output of this router. So if the destination is 22 then we have X-axis routing first so the flits will exit the east port and move until they reach router 02 and then they will be router to the Y-axis to head up to router 22.

I hope you can understand what I am saying!

If not please let me know!

With regards

Comment: No problem. So what you're saying is that each output FIFO is connected to every input FIFO? If so, is it possible for multiple output FIFO's trying to write to the same input FIFO in the same cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Controlling an **input FIFO**: Use the full signal of that input FIFO and the empty signal of the corresponding output FIFO to generate the write enable signal (condition: write when the input FIFO is not full and the output FIFO is not empty, i.e. new data is available and can be written)
- Controlling an **output FIFO**: Use the read enable signal of the corresponding input FIFO as write enable (if data was read it must be removed from the output FIFO to avoid being read multiple times by the input FIFO)

I don't understand what you're doing with the 6 bits you mention. Is this the address of the input FIFO where the data item of the output FIFO should be written to? If you clarify I can update my reply.

Comment: I have edited my original message in order to answer to your question Simon!I could not write the whole message here because I was out of characters!



I really appreciate or your time and answer

Comment: Hello there again!

Basically yes!All input fifos communicate with all the output fifos of the ports!In order to avoid congestion at each output block I have a round-robin- arbiter that handles multiple requests.

So for example all the input ports (N,S,W,E,L) request the NORTH output port.The arbiter will handle them and serve only one request. Then sends a control signal to the central switch which comprises of MUXs and only the winning input data go through to the NORTH output fifo!

Comment: So my problem is in how to control the signals of the input/output fifo and the other problem is how will the input fifo take the signals needed from the output fifo after arbitration!I mean it could be either of the 5 output fifos!

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. First, I think only a maximum of 4 input FIFOs can request the same output FIFO. It makes no sense that that the input FIFO of a port wants to write data to the output FIFO of the same port, right (4:1 MUX is nicer than 5:1 MUX :))? So basically, each output FIFO has a 4:1 MUX to which the 4 input FIFOs of the other ports are connected. The arbiter must then generate the correct control signals for the MUX of each port as well as a write enable signal for each port. I'm not sure if this is your problem though.

Comment: Hi there mate again thank you for you time!

Basically you are getting it right!The mux is not that of a problem!I mean most of the paper I ve read on this matter talk about 5:1 mux but thats not the problem for my router which complexity and scalability are low.
My problem is to understand where the input fifo (write_enable , read_enable, full , empty ) and respectively the output fifo's I/O ports must be connected! I will use internal signals declaration for the router in orderto connect the signals needed to the I/O ports of the fifo!

Comment: So basically : The input fifo in order to store data , full must be low and write_en must be high. What is the use ofthe empty signal?
When the fifo gets full , full goes high and write_en goes low. And then if the output fifo has room to store so full is low the read_en of the input fifo will go high! Or it can go high either way and let the arbiter check the output fifo fullness !So if the arbiter checks the output fifo andits full it wont send the control signal to the mux! But again what about the empty signal. I mean basically that's my problem!If I am thinking correctly.
Cheers andthnx:)

Comment: The empty signal is required to generate the input FIFO's read enable signal. You're not allowed to set ren high when the FIFO is empty because it will possibly (this depends on the FIFO implementation) result in undefined behaviour (e.g. the internal counter will roll over). The output FIFO's that can be used to route the messages in the input FIFO must check if the input FIFO is empty or not (if it is, the output data is not valid!). Only if it is not empty they should read from the input FIFO. So basically ren = (not input_empty) and (not output_full)!

Comment: Ok mate thank you 1000 times! 
Let me recap to see if I am getting it right. 
Lets say that have one router with the input and outpuf fifo. 
The input fifo wr_en can be high only if the fifo sending data is not empty and this fifo is not full.
So wr_en <= (not previous empty) and (not local full)
And in order for the read_enable to be high the local's fifo empty must be low and the destination's Fifo must not be full.

So read_en <= (not local empty) and (next fifo not full)

Comment: The same for the output fifo!
rd_en <= (not local fifo empty) and ( not next fifo full)
wr_en <= ( previous not empty) and (local not full)

The thing is that the signal of the output fifo will be also checked by the arbiter. If the output fifo is full then the arbiter will not issue a grant signal to the mux!Dose this matter?I mean it wont cause any problems right?

And one final question...

Do you know how to make transparent the first 6 bits going in the input fifo to use the for routing?Or a way to extract them?

Cheers mate and thnx for everything!If you come to London I ll buy beers :)

Comment: I will check again and update my response as soon as I have more time. Thanks for the beers :P

Comment: Hi there mate can I ask you something final?
Is there a way to extract the first 6 bits coming in the FIFO in order to use them in my routing logic? How can I extract these bits?